# Объясните, пожалуйста, как происходит вывод двумерного массива на Java?

Tags: java, массивы

```java
int[][] nums = new int[][]
{
  { 1, 2, 3 },
  { 4, 5, 6 },
  { 7, 8, 9 }
};

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; j++) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", nums[i][j]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Пытаюсь понять, почему во вложенном цикле `for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; j++)` `j < nums[i]`. Ведь получается, если `j < nums[i].length`, то он же не будет выполняться? Или как вообще это происходит, не понимаю?

Comment: Странно, что внешний цикл у вас не вызывает вопросов, хотя там написано то же самое.

Comment: я не понимаю принцип работы именно вложенного цикла

Comment: Принцип работы внешнего цикла понятен? Внутренний работает точно так же. Все циклы работают одинаково.

Comment: Срочно брать учебник и читать, что означает условие j < y в цикле.

Comment: окей :// но вы, наверное, не поняли моего вопроса. я понимаю что значит внешний цикл, что он будет выполняться до конца длины массива, т.е. он для строк, как я поняла. но тут появляется еще и j, которая будет выполняться пока <nums[i].length. но если j = 1 или 2 а i будет все еще на нулевом, то j же получается больше чем i-тый.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что такое nums[i]? А что такое nums[i].length? А разницу между ``j < i`` и ``j < nums[i].length`` видите?

Comment: nums[i] - это индекс элемента в массиве, a nums[i].length - это вроде быы длина строки?

Comment: Нет. num[i] это не индекс элемента, а сам элемент. В данном случае тоже массив, одноимерный. А nums[i].length его длина.

Answer (score 1):

Цикл с условием `j < nums[i].length` выполняется до тех пор, пока j не станет равным `nums[i].length` (в вашем случае это всегда 3). Значение `i` к этому условию не имеет отношения, оно всего лишь определяет какая строка выводится.

*num[i] это элемент массива nums,  т.е. каждый отдельный вложенный массив.*